# Unable to interact with .class files

Tags: java, class, classpath, jgrasp

everyone! I am trying to work on a simple program that takes a command-line argument, and passes it as a parameter to a function from a Text.class file that our professor instructed us to download, and place in the working directory. I placed it in the same folder that contained the .java file. I think that is where I went wrong, could someone please offer me some assistance? Thank you :)

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g /home/seedl/Documents/School/CSx/Programming Assignments/#1/SpeedPrinter/src/speedprinter/SpeedPrinter.java
SpeedPrinter.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        Text.toNonnegativeDouble(args[0]);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Text
  location: class SpeedPrinter
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Text.class to your classpath. If you're running from command line, use java -cp %path_to_Text.class%. If you're running from an IDE, you can add folders to your classpath, so they can be included in your program,